# ORA-01722: invalid number only in Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I have a weird issue. I created a table to store a daily snapshot of a view. The view (SOME_CALC) and the table (SOME_CALC_HIST) have the same definition, something like

```
Col_Name       |Type      |Nullable
---------------|----------|--------
UPDATE_INST    |DATE      |Y          <- only in the table, SYSDATE
ITEM_NAME      |VARCHAR2  |Y          <- (should be a) numeric string
CALC_VALUE     |NUMBER    |Y          <- filled by a ROUND(SUM(VALUE), 0) in the view    
DATA_DATE      |DATE      |Y          <- filled by a SELECT(MAX(INST)) FROM... in the view
```

The idea is to have a view that calculates for each ITEM_NAME a CALC_VALUE based on current data and a set of data from DATA_DATE. Every day a mechanism (that is not covered here, it works for every other instance) runs a procedure (SOME_CALC_APPEND) that does more or less nothing but

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "SOME_CALC_APPEND" AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO SOME_CALC_HIST
    SELECT SYSDATE, * FROM SOME_CALC
END
```

While I can execute the section between BEGIN and END without any errors as well as executing the complete procedure, the very same function throws an error ORA-01722 when it is run as a scheduled job.

Does anyone see any possible issue that I might have missed? I don't want to dig into the scheduling thing since that is third party stuff that runs robust and stable for years.

I know this is a bit vague and not very detailed but alas that is all info I have. My first guess was ITEM_NAME since it is something like a serial number and used to be NUMBER, so I changed that. The error was still there and the only left number is the CALC_VALUE.

**CODE REPO:**

_SOME_CALC_HIST_

```
CREATE TABLE SOME_CALC_HIST
   (    "UPDATE_INST" DATE DEFAULT sysdate, 
    "ITEM_NAME" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "CALC_VALUE" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "DATA_DATE" DATE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
  NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
   STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
   TABLESPACE ".." ;
```

_SOME_CALC_

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW SOME_CALC ("ITEM_NAME", "CALC_VALUE", "DATA_DATE") AS 
  SELECT
  VT.ITEM_NAME
, VT.CALC_VALUE
, (SELECT MAX(UPDATED_INST) FROM SOURCE_2) AS DATA_DATE
FROM (
  SELECT
    VT.ITEM_NAME
    ROUND(SUM(VALUE), 0)     AS CALC_VALUE
  FROM SOURCE_1 VT
  GROUP BY VT.ITEM_NAME
) VT;
```

**On the scheduling mechanism:**

There is a mechanism with to configuration tables CFG_PROCEDURES and CFG_SCHED. I have to put a procedure in the CFG_PROCEDURES tables first to "register" the procedure for the scheduling mechanism:

```
Procedure_Name   | Owner
-----------------|-----------
SOME_CALC_APPEND | my Schema
```

Then I can schedule the procedure as a job in CFG_SCHED:

```
Interval|Order|Procedure
--------|-----|----------------
daily   | 1   |SOME_CALC_APPEND
```

Another view ensures that all grants are set correctly and creates code to set missing grants.
Now, every day (hour, minute, what have you) all daily jobs (procedures) are run in the given order.

Down the road, the mechanism uses a function LOAD_OBJECT('object') to execute the scheduled object. When I do that manually

```
exec LOAD_OBJECT('SOME_CALC_APPEND');
```

it works.

Comment: Can you share the query code for your table structure?

Comment: @Gerry, what do you mean? Like the CREATE code for the SOME_CALC_HIST? I'll try to provide a bit more code

Comment: you do insert into a table, I just want to see the sql code for that table.

Comment: Do you schedule the actual procedure to run each time? In other words do you run the actual procedure as a job?

Comment: @Gerry, As far as I know, I do. There is some fancy mechanism where I register the procedure within a table. Then I can create a job in a different table, where I also enter the procedure name and an interval. A administrative view checks for grants and creates sql code to set missing ones. Fancy stuff..

Comment: The one problem is that if you run a create view as a job, you would need to put replace as part of the code, if it exists it will not recreate it, so I doubt that the issue is with the procedure, can you post the Job code?

Comment: I am going to post an answer as the comments allow little space, so do not downvote as I will then edit the answer once I get the job code.

Comment: I don't recreate the view. The job is only the short procedure "SOME_CALC_APPEND"

Comment: Sorry, I meant recreate the procedure, not the view.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I do not think the problem is with the procedure code, I think the job is passing the incorrect values to the procedure.

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE "SOME_CALC_APPEND" (AUTHID, CURRENT_USER) AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO SOME_CALC_HIST (UPDATE_INST, ITEM_NAME, CALC_VALUE, DATA_DATE)
VALUES (SYSDATE, (select ITEM_NAME from SOME_CALC), (select CALC_VALUE from SOME_CALC), (select DATA_DATE from SOME_CALC))
END
```

EDITED!

Please can you try this and let me know?

Comment: Now I got you. You mean the caller! That is buried deep and I am not sure whether I want to open that box if it is not necessary since the mechanism normally works very well..

Comment: ok, I am with you. It is difficult for me to re-create the scenario without all the relevant scenarios, but let's not complicate this. Let me rather suggest a different procedure. Do you insert AUTHID and CURRENT_USER into SOME_CALC_HIST as values?

Comment: Not beyond the CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SOME_CALC_APPEN AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS
BEGIN.. stuff. No Sir, I think I do not.

Comment: Hey @Gerry: You are asking the right question, good rubber ducking. I unburied the caller function and I can call that one with my procedure as an argument manually. It runs without the error. I wonder whether this is a timing problem..

Comment: I made the procedure do a similar thing, but by giving all the values manually, can you try that please?

Comment: That works. Hm.. I have a clue.. please hold your work, this could be the issue.

Comment: No, still not working. I found a bad GROUP BY clause down the rabbit hole. I encountered a weird error once, that was caused by such a thing. Like working when watched but going awry when not overwatched.

Comment: Yes, I do. I am pretty sure now, it is nothing with my code but with the 3 party product scheduler.

Comment: My thoughts as well, I cannot really see any issues with the code here.

Comment: Okay, thanks, captain. I will reach out to them. I really appreciated your support.

Comment: Great, hope you get to a solution asap.

Comment: @Gerry I agree with you. been doing alot of procedures recently in Apex and does not seem to be any issues with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Supply the column names in the both insert script and select statement.

Example...

```
INSERT INTO SOME_CALC_HIST(UPDATE_INST, ITEM_NAME, CALC_VALUE, DATA_DATE)
SELECT SYSDATE, ITEM_NAME, CALC_VALUE, DATA_DATE FROM SOME_CALC
```

Answer (score -1):

did you try convert string to number, like this to_number(mystring)?

Comment: No, but I don't think I have to since the only numbers come out of a calculation and that runs without errors. The result is only 20+ lines and all numbers are well-formed numbers, when I run the view manually.

Comment: This is not related.